# Почему компилятор пишет, что переменная не инициализирована

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

хочу написать функцию, которая принимает другую указатель на другую функцию и выводит тип принимаемых параметров.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;


inline void boo() {}

template <typename first, typename... other> void boo(first fst, other... Other)
{
    cout << typeid(first).name() << endl;
    boo(Other...);
}

template<typename R,typename ... args>
void foo(R(*ptr)(args... xc))
{   
    boo(xc...);
}


void xf(int a, int b) {}


int main()
{
    foo(xf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boo` не нужна, типы аргументов уже получены - `args`, их можно сразу выводить.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename R,typename ... args>
void foo(R(*ptr)(args...))
{   
    ((::std::cout << typeid(args).name() << ' '), ...) << '\n';
}

void xf(int a, int b) {}

int main()
{
    foo(xf);
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:11,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:11,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:11,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:11,startLineNumber:12),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctypeinfo%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+R,typename+...+args%3E%0Avoid+foo(R(*ptr)(args...))%0A%7B+++%0A++++((::std::cout+%3C%3C+typeid(args).name()+%3C%3C+!%27+!%27),+...)+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+xf(int+a,+int+b)+%7B%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++foo(xf)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g131,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Answer (score 3):

`R(*ptr)(args... xc)` : `ptr` - это указатель на функцию с типами `args`. Имя переменных `xc` игнорируется при указании типа функций. Дополнительный аргумент `xc` нужно передавать отдельным аргументом в функцию `foo`.

```cpp
template <typename first, typename... other>
void boo(first fst, other... Other)
{
    cout << typeid(first).name() << "=" << fst << endl;
    boo(Other...);
}

template<typename R,typename ... args>
void foo(R(*ptr)(args... ),args... xc){
  boo(xc...);
}

int main(){
  foo(xf,1,2);
}
```